# how to get selected id inside interval using jquery

Tags: jquery

Having this piece of code and i want to get selected element id (popup_w) but this.id or $(this).attr('id') or $this returning undefined...

Is there any problem with interval? How i will get the selected element id?

```js
console.clear();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $("body").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var found = false;
var checkDiv = setInterval( function() {
  
  if ( $("div[id$='_w']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
    console.log( this.id ); 
  };
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Comment: `this`  does not refer to appended element

Comment: `i want to get selected element id`:- what do you mean by `selected element id`?

Comment: I don't understand how there are so many answers here altough nobody understands the question...

Comment: @Esko, I think OP is trying to get the ID of new inserted div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of `setInterval` for listening changes to [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $(".container").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var element = document.querySelector('.container');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "childList") {
      console.log("New Node inserted with ID", mutation.addedNodes[0].id);
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  childList: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: at-least you can suggest to use `class` instead of `id`. BTW answer is perfect to me

Comment: @Satpal MutationObserver for javascript beginners, seriously? :)

Comment: @loelsonk, yep Everyone was a beginner once, learning correct approach is more important in initial years

Comment: @AlivetoDie, OP must be performing some operation based on ID/Popup

Comment: loelsonk is right.. but i will search about MutationObserver.
Thank you Satpal

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get Id `$("div[id$='_w']")[0].id`

**EDIT:** You can use `$("div[id$='_w']").attr('id')`. Thanks [satpal](/users/1668533/satpal) for suggestion.

```js
console.clear();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $("body").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var found = false;
var checkDiv = setInterval( function() {
  
  if ( $("div[id$='_w']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
    console.log( $("div[id$='_w']")[0].id ); 
    console.log( $("div[id$='_w']").attr('id'));
  };
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Comment: @TakisMichalopoulos Glad that it helped you.

Comment: @TakisMichalopoulos Using `setInterval` is bad approach, go ahead if it suits you and as you are using jQuery why not `$("div[id$='_w']").attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks @satpal , I understand your concern. Code has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

console.clear();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $("body").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
    $("body").prepend('<div id="popup2_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var found = false;
var checkDiv = setInterval( function() {
  if ( $("div[id$='_w']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
     $("div[id$='_w']").each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).attr('id') ); 
     })
    
  };
  
}, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Notice that `each` loop which is very useful if you are expecting to get the id of several div that has `_w` as a part of the `id` attribute.

Comment: This works too. I will use yours because its more simple than Hassan's snippet.
Thank you AKA.

Comment: It only works when you have only one id with `_w` as a part of the id.

Comment: Yes i understand... Only one at the time popup opens

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setInterval` use jQuery custom event handler.

First we generate random new Id, then we `trigger` new event called `elementAdded`.

`param1` is your `id` attribute, you can easly access now your newly created element via `$('#' + param1);`

See working example.

```js
console.clear();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var newId = makeid();
   $("body").prepend('<div id="' + newId + '">A new popup div added</div>');
   $("body").trigger("elementAdded", [ newId ]);
});

 $("body").on("elementAdded", function (event, param1) {
   // our new button
  var element = $('#' + param1);
  // Access your element $('#' + param1)
  console.log(element.length); // if 1 element is found any usable 
});
            
            

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 if ( $("div[id^='popup_']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
    console.log($('div').attr('id')); 
  };
```

Example:-

```js
console.clear();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $("body").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var found = false;
var checkDiv = setInterval( function() {
  
  if ( $("div[id^='popup_']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
    console.log($('div').attr('id')); 
  };
  
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
```

Comment: a need to query _w not the popup_ .
But if i used this popup_  like the way you say it return undefined too..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.each** function.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   $("body").prepend('<div id="popup_w">A new popup div added</div><div id="Spopup_w">A new popup div added</div>');
});

var found = false;
var checkDiv = setInterval( function() {

  if ( $("div[id$='_w']").length && !found) {  
    found = true;
    $("div[id$='_w']").each(function(){
        console.log(  this.id  ); 
    })

  };

}, 1000);
```